# EJB injection in Netbeans

Tags: ejb, cdi

I try to use CDI between to separate projects in Netbeans.
I have two projects, caller and calledon. The idea is that the caller calls calledon.
The problem is when I try to implement the call using *@EJB CalledOn* in the caller-project the interfaces from the calledon project are not available.
I can solve that by adding the jar-file of calledon to the caller project but then I have created a dependency that calledon must be compiled before it can be used.

Is there a way to only use the local inteface in the .java file instead?

Comment: You have to split the project in two projects. One for the interface and one for the implementation

Comment: I already have to projects, the caller and the calledon.

Comment: But the caller and the calledon share some files: the interfaces. Now you have to create a third project for the interfaces

Comment: In what way will a third project not make a compile time dependency between caller and calledon? Netbeans seems only capable of using compiled classes using the classpath and not ,java files so the new project would also have to be compiled?

Comment: You can reference other projects in NetBeans